# How to implement Janrain Engage in ASP.NET / C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, janrain

I can't figure out where the C# helper class goes in my project (using VS2010).  I'm following the tutorial at https://sites.google.com/a/janrain.com/developers/articles/engage-tutorial but it's in PHP.  In this context, is "rpx.php" analogous to "rpx.aspx", "rpx.aspx.cs", or "rpx.cs"?  Know what I mean?

Or, does anyone know of a C# Janrain tutorial/example?  That would keep me from posting my next dozen questions.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `php` file will be most closely analogous to the code behind file `rpx.aspx.cs`.

Though, in the .NET world, both the `.aspx` and the `.aspx.cs` files are closely related.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you would create an rpx.aspx page which would then handle the process in the code-behind.

However, since you are using VS.NET 2010 (and therefore, ASP.NET 4), There are two things I'd recommend, either creating an [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) implementation or using [Routing in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) to create a "pretty" URL that links to an ASPX page.

Either way, you would handle the callback from Janrain in your `IHttpHandler`/ASPX page, verifying the token and then redirecting to an appropriate page.

Comment: Thanks! For clarification, you're suggesting I use routing to land the user on some page (Default.aspx?id=somedude) that pulls their unique content from the db, etc., post authentication?

Comment: @America: No, I'm suggesting you use routing for the callback page you give to Janrain; the code-behind of that page will redirect to whatever page you want once you've handled the response from Janrain (this usually involves a redirect back to the page the user was looking at).